# How set works with 'abc' and 'bac' in Python?

Tags: python, set, character

if we use:

```
set('abc')
```

we will get :

```
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

My question is why not:

```
set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Thank you!

Comment: `set`s are unordered collections.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate. Nevertheless, the `set` and `dictionary` types are unordered, and their representations are based on the hash values of the items (not useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W3schools answer: Sets are unordered, so the items will appear in a random order.

Read more about them:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp

:)